# Definir una función en pandas que cambie el formato de columnas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Intento definir una función en la que me cambie el formato de varias columnas de varios pd.DataFrame(). El cambio en los números consiste en cambiar el lugar del signo “-” que se encuentra atrás del número.

`df= pd.DataFrame({“Column1”: [“1,000-“,”2,000-“,”2,000-“]})`

El codigo estandar es este, pero no se como transformarlo a funcion:

`A=pd.DataFrame(df[“Column1”].str.replace(“-“, “-1”).str.split(“-“, expand=True)).rename(columns={0:”Valor”, 1:”Signo”})`
`A[“Neg”]=np.where(A.Signo==“1”,”-“,””)`
`A=A.Neg.str.cat(A.Valor)`

`df[“Columns1”]=A.str.replace(“.”,””).str.replace(“,”,”.”).astype(float)`

La salida es deseada es:

`df=pd.DataFrame({“Column1”:[-1,-2,-2]})`

Pero para distintos DataFrames y distintas columnas.

Answer (score 1):

te comparto el codigo para convertirlo en una funcion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({"Column1": ["1,000-", "2,000-", "2,000-"]})

def cambio(nombre):
    A= pd.DataFrame(df[nombre].str.replace("-", "-1").str.split("-", expand=True)).rename(columns={0:"Valor", 1:"Signo"}) 
    A["Neg"]= np.where(A.Signo=="1","-","") 
    A= A.Neg.str.cat(A.Valor)
    return A.str.replace(".","").str.replace(",",".").astype(float)

    
print(cambio("Column1"))
```

Si te fijas, habias conseguido lo mas complicado que era hacer esos cambios en el DataFrame.

Para convertirlo en una funcion, simplemente creo la funcion pasandole por parametro un nombre, el cual sera el nombre de la columna del dataframe que quieres cambiar, para este caso "Column1".
Una vez que este creada la funcion, meto el codigo que has pasado, el cual hace su tarea correctamente, pero cambiando "Column1" por *nombre* para que la funcion sea usada para cualquiera DataFrame.

Finalmente, se retorna la variable "A" que habias creado y hago un print de la funcion para que veas el resultado (El cual he probado y funciona correctamente). De todas formas, comentarte que lo que retorna la funcion es un DataFrame, en este caso el DataFrame modificado.

Un saludo, espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Necesito que el return sea que me reemplace la columna. Solo me faltaría eso. Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Es decir que al ejecutar df.Column1, me aparezca la columna con las modificaciones

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que necesitas es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) para poder aplicar la función deseada a las "celdas" de tu serie.

En primer lugar, hay una forma más sencilla de tarnsformar el `string` que tienes al formato deseado. Si te fijas, el signo `-` siempre está en el último caracter del `string` por lo que si utilizas el índice `-1` podrás obtener el signo negativo. El valor numérico va desde el índice `0` hasta el penúltimo elemento por lo que podrías utilizar `slicing` (Segmentación) para dar el formato adecuado.

Si tenemos una fila `row` y deseamos cambiar la posición del signo de la última posición del `string` a la primera, es decir, como si recorrieramos circularmente a la derecha se puede hacer así:

```
row[-1] + row[:-1]
```

Lo demás ya lo tienes, que es reemplazar los puntos `.` por un `string` vacío `''` y las comas `,` por puntos `.`:

```
(row[-1] + row[:-1]).replace('.','').replace(',','.')
```

Por último convertimos el número a `float`:

```
float((row[-1] + row[:-1]).replace('.','').replace(',','.'))
```

Poniendo todo esto en una función quedaría así:

```
def cambio(row):
    return float((row[-1] + row[:-1]).replace('.','').replace(',','.'))
```

Para utilizar esa función con una serie (Columna) utilizamos `apply`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

def cambio(row):
    return float((row[-1] + row[:-1]).replace('.','').replace(',','.'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['1,000-','2,000-','2,000-', '3.500,2-']})

df['Column2'] = df['Column1'].apply(cambio)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Column1  Column2
0    1,000-     -1.0
1    2,000-     -2.0
2    2,000-     -2.0
3  3.500,2-  -3500.2
```

**Nota:** Yo cree una nueva columna "Column2" para poder comparar el resultado final con el valor inicial y ver que realmente funciona, pero si lo que deseas es sobreescribir "Column1", entonces hazlo así:

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(cambio)
```

Comment: Es decir que no es posible que la función me reemplace directamente la columna? Porque si lo necesito hacer para 30 columnas sería muy largo

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más sobre lo que deseas hacer? Es decir la meta final? Porque si tienes muchas columnas iguales y tú plan es hacer un ciclo `for` con esa función que reemplace los valores de la columna entonces es el camino incorrecto. La librería `pandas` tiene métodos optimizados para trabajar con los `dataframes` y los ciclos deben ser la última opción a sabiendas que sería el camino más lento o el que consume más recursos. Si editas tu pregunta y agregas las otras columnas y un ejemplo del resultado puedo ayudarte a encontrar una forma de hacerlo.